# Highstocks date tooltip lose format after data update

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highstocks to plot a near real time time series. The problem is when I update it's data, the date tooltip looses it's format.

Here is the date tooltip before the first refresh:

[image]

Here is the date tooltip after the first refresh:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using `chart.series.data[index].update()` to update the data.

Edit1: after updating the series, I use `chart.redraw()`.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue with the sample data on some online editor which I could debug? From screens, it's hard to say what could have an impact on it.